# How to unify History from Internet Explorer and Mozilla Firefox

Tags: firefox, internet, browser, internet-explorer, history

I'm using Internet Explorer and Mozilla Firefox. Each for different things. Is it possible to somehow "unify" browsing history from bouth of these browsers so that sites I have visited while on Firefox also would be stored in Explorers history and vice versa?

Comment: Are you looking to do a one-time import or keep them synced?

Comment: For a 2 way real time sync @Julian Knight is correct.  You would have to manually use firefox to import IE history every time you wanted to sync.  Then only Firefox would have all the history.  IE allows Feeds,Favorites, and Cookies to be imported.  My from other browser is disabled for some reason.

Comment: @PFitz: I'm looking to keep them synced.

Comment: @Mate Gotcha. In that case, my answer below isn't all that helpful. I'll update the answer with some more info...

Answer (score 1):

In short, no.

IE is well integrated to the OS and uses its own temporary folder areas. Firefox is designed to be cross-OS and uses a very different folder structure.

What is more, they both use different file formats.

The only way to do this would be to have an application that trawled through the history folders of each, parsed the data and created its own history list. Possibly, you could do this with something like Microsoft Excel though it would be better done in PowerShell or a scripting language.

Comment: OK, why the downvote - please explain rather than being rude.